# What is happening to this vacuum tube?

Tags: power-electronics, vacuum-tube

I’m trying to repair a 63 year old record player. Opening it up, *all* of the electronics have aged badly, except for the drive motor, which is basic enough that it operates properly. I know enough about the resistors and capacitors that I can just get modern equivalents that will last much longer than their 50s counterparts, but what I’m concerned about are the vacuum tubes, one 35W4 and a 50C5.

[image]
[image]

This image is of the tube’s socket pins. The top tube is the 35W4, while the bottom tube is the 50C5. You can see a bright bluish-white line of electricity connecting two pins together. It doesn’t seem to go away until I cut the power. The 50C5 seems to be experiencing spark gaps, if that’s the proper term, between pins 6 and 7, along with making an annoying buzzing noise. I don’t leave it powered on because I don’t know if it will start a fire, explode, etc. Tubes aren’t my specialty, but I know they’re dangerous. Does this mean anything is happening to the tube? Is it faulty?

Here is a picture of the record player schematic.
[image]

The white powdery substance is just a 250 ohm Lectrohm resistor, I’m not sure why it uses powder, it is some 60 years old, but it isn’t functional and the resistance has dropped drastically.

Comment: Did you observe the sparking associated with the 50C5 inside the glass envelope of the tube, or at the socket pins under the chassis?  If in the glass tube, is there a white milky tint anywhere inside the glass?  If at the socket pins, you need to identify in the photograph which one is the 50C5:  upper or lower tube?  To the right of the sockets, what is that white powdery substance?

Comment: @AlmostDone The 50C5 would seem to be the bottom tube. Inside the 50C5, Pin 5 and Pin 2 are both wired to the internal grid 1. And I can see that pin 5 on that socket isn't wired to anything, which is reasonable if they used Pin 2, instead, for wiring externally. But Pin 5 is the plate for the 35W4 diode. So that's kind of important and would have been used. So I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @AlmostDone Added note: All *mysterious white powdery substances* are, by definition, *anthrax*. Or so it seems at times when listening to the news in the US.

Comment: @jonk Yes, see that now, wasn't visible on my phone.  Shielded input to the grid at pin 2.  I suspect the white powder indicates the bottom of a dried up chassis mount electrolytic.

Comment: @toasthouse If you're sincerely trying to restore this, my advice is to first replace the parts that by inspection you know or suspect to be bad, including the tubes.  The tubes should be available through antique radio sources and ham radio flea markets.

Comment: Cannot tell if blue arc is through air or over the surface of the phenolic tube socket. A good cleaning (and drying) of the socket may help. 50C5 and 35W4 are intended to have filaments wired in series, along with a dropping resistor directly to 120V AC. Could that be your failing 250 ohm?

Comment: I think it’s connected to the metal. I didn’t get too close, I don’t know what to expect from it. Perhaps the resistor is affecting it. It isn’t even close to 250 ohms.

Comment: as AlmostDone said, replace the things that you can see are faulty. If the tubes are silver on top, they are full of vacuum. If they are white on top, the vacuum has leaked out. Arcing probably means the phenolic is tracking - it will be blackened, and I expect you can smell burning phenolic. Cut or drill burnt phenolic away, and put a bit of plastic in. If the arc is through the air, then for some reason there is a very high voltage - it takes a lot more than normal tube circuit voltages to cause air to arc

Comment: Both of the tubes are black on top. If you’re right about arcing being caused by a very high voltage, then I suspect that it may be the Lectrohm 250 resistor. As @glen_geek said, the tubes are wired in series, with a resistor in between. He is correct about the resistor being in between. I have uploaded the schematic of the record player in my question.

Comment: @HenryCrun: "*The tubes ... are full of vacuum.*" This is a lovely picture.

Comment: Just because nobody else has pointed it out, you need to be very careful with this circuit, even more so then with the usual sort of valve based thing. This one is LIVE CHASSIS so an isolating transformer is more or less mandatory if you are going to work on the thing. I am guessing that this was originally inside a wooden box with no access to the metalwork or any other connections? If the resistor R4 has really gone very low (Note it is shunted by the motor winding) I would expect the filaments to have died.

Comment: Arc is between plate and screen grid, which *should have similar DC voltage*. Always replace electrolytic capacitors - in your case 3 are required: a low voltage 20uf, and two high-voltage 40uf, 60uf.

Comment: @Dan Mills yes, the record player was screwed inside a wooden box. I don’t touch anything when I have it plugged in it turned on. If resistor R4 is the main problem, would a modern equivalent function just as well as this powdered one? I would only be able to unsolder it, as it is part of the chassis.

Comment: @glen_geek Thanks, I will replace these capacitors, as their values have dropped to 10 and even as low as 2.

Comment: Will the modern counterparts really last longer? I have my doubts